# How to repair SQLServerCE Database programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

How can I repair SQLServerCE Database from C# code.
I am using this call:

```
engine.Repair(GetDBConnectionString(), RepairOption.RecoverAllOrFail);
```

where GetDBConnectionString() is a private function that builds Connection String for me. 
But this raises exception:
"The file that is being referenced is not a SQL Server Compact database file format"

Regards,
Pawel

Comment: Then your file is not a SQL Server Compact database file, or really corrupted, Have you tried the file version detector in the SQL CE Toolbox against the file?

Comment: I haven't mentioned but I was able to repair database with your tool: SQL Server Compact Toolbox => Maintenance => Repair (recover all or fail). I wonder how to do it the same from C# code, so program operating on database could it repair by itself.

Comment: OK. You are maybe using the wrong ADO.NET version in your own app? I think you may get this error if you use version 3.5.1 against a 4.0 database

Comment: You are right. That was a problem of version. Thank you.

Comment: Erik, can you guess what can be a reason of database corruptions? It happens from time to time.

Comment: It could be that you are sharing SqlCeConnection /SqlCeCommand objects across thread, or you have a faulty disk. Make sure to run the latest engine build for the version you use. On WM devices, there can also be storage driver bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong ADO.NET version in your own app. I think you may get this error if you use version 3.5.1 against a 4.0 database